# Need to Remove Duplicate wrapped class of div in Jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

i have HTML structure of div like this:

```
<div id="someid">
<div class="new"><div class="new"><img src="https://www.something.com/image1.jpg"></div></div>
<div class="new"><div class="new"><img src="https://www.something.com/image2.jpg"></div></div>
<div class="new"><img src="https://www.something.com/image3.jpg"></div>
<div class="new"><div class="new"><img src="https://www.something.com/image4.jpg"></div></div>
</div>
```

But i want this structure `Output` as something like this:

```
<div id="someid">
<div class="new"><img src="https://www.something.com/image1.jpg"></div>
<div class="new"><img src="https://www.something.com/image2.jpg"></div>
<div class="new"><img src="https://www.something.com/image3.jpg"></div>
<div class="new"><img src="https://www.something.com/image4.jpg"></div>
</div>
```

How can I do this job with `jQuery`, any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can select the inner `.new` and `.unwrap()` them :

```js
$(".new > .new").unwrap()
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="someid">
  <div class="new">
    <div class="new"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="new">
    <div class="new"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="new"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100"></div>
  <div class="new">
    <div class="new"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```